# Symfony - configure existing project on localhost

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am new to Symfony. I want to start work with existing project. I downloaded sources to the localhost. I configured apache and when I try to run /index.php (from web dir) or frontend.php it gives me a blank page. Why?
I don't have database configured. I can't do

```
php symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

It says that there are no tasks defined in doctrine namespace.

EDIT
There was no cache dir. I created it and now I get error page (internal server error). Probably it's because database is not configured. How to configure it by schema.yml?

Comment: check `app/AppKernel.php` for a line that contains `DoctrineBundle`. If not, have you downloaded the [symfony-standard](http://symfony.com/download) distribution ?

Comment: @miguel_ibero since he's talking about index.php, frontend_dev.php and not app_dev.php I guess he is using symfony 1.4.

Comment: I missed the `php symfony` part, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using symfony 1.4, or tell me if I'm wrong.

You can check the getting started from the symfony website: http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/02-Prerequisites which is a very good start point to have a dev env.

Try als to launch these commands:

```
php symfony project:permissions
php symfony cc
```